# MySQL query from different tables based on a field of a table

Tags: mysql

I think the title is a bit vague. I'll explain below.
So I have these tables

> appointments table

```
id  created_by  created_by_id
---------------------------
1   provider        10
2   customer        5
3   admin           1
```

> providers table

```
id first_name last_name
------------------------
..    ...       ...
10     x         y
```

> customers table

```
id  first_name  last_name
-------------------------
..     ...       ...
5       a         b
```

> admins table

```
id  first_name  last_name
--------------------------
..    ...          ...
1      c            d
```

I want to query and return full name of the relevant account based on created_by field, so if it is provider, it query the name in provider table, and so on.

I have tried this

```
select  *,
        (
            SELECT 
                CASE 
                    WHEN appointments.created_by='provider' THEN 
                        CONCAT(d.first_name, " ", d.last_name)
                    WHEN appointments.created_by='customer' THEN 
                        CONCAT(p.first_name, " ", p.last_name)
                    ELSE CONCAT(p.first_name, " ", p.last_name)
                END
            FROM providers as d, customers as p
            WHERE 
                appointments.created_by_id = (CASE 
                    WHEN appointments.created_by='provider' THEN 
                        d.id
                    WHEN appointments.created_by='customer' THEN 
                        p.id
                    ELSE p.id
                END)
        )
from appointments
```

But it doesn't seem to work.
Could you please help me to achieve a table like this

```
id  created_by  name
-------------------
1    provider   x y
2    customer   a b
3     admin     c d
```

Comment: If it is possible, you could do some restructuring in you database like this: https://gist.github.com/makallio85/7aa6a2b1cd7fa17ab35f that will make db-schema much more understable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select *,
    case appointments.created_by 
        when 'admin' then (select concat(first_name, ' ', last_name)  from admins where admins.id = appointments.created_by_id)
        when 'customer' then (select concat(first_name, ' ', last_name)  from customers where customers.id=appointments.created_by_id)
        when 'provider' then (select concat(first_name, ' ', last_name)  from providers where providers.id = appointments.created_by_id)
    END as name
from appointments
```

Here is a sqlfiddle with the case method: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/43510/1

Comment: I don't know how it compares for performance but my first take was to use a UNION of the three tables. If the tables get too large you may want to compare the execution plans and performance of the two methods.